# Importando p/ Mysql a partir de TXT

Tags: php, importação

Tenho um arquivo txt vindo de um banco de dados que separa os itens com um espaço tipo o TAB, o item primeiro é o nome do produto, o segundo item do txt é o valor, tipo isto, eu preciso saber como fazer o php importar desta forma separando os campos corretamente, o que podem me indicar estudar de forma mais direta possivel algum tutorial por exemplo ?

Linguagem: PHP

Comment: Você precisa importar isso só uma vez ou vai ser uma funcionalidade do seu sistema?

Comment: Vai ter a opção Importar arquivo, e vai esquecer todo banco anterior e substituir pelos dados atuais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solução basica

```
 // Abrir documento fonte
 $name_src = "nome_documento.txt";
 $h_src = fopen($name_src,"r");


 // Leitura linha depois linha até o final
 while (($str_src = fgets($h_src)) !== false)
 {

    // Explode sobre TAB
    $tab = explode("\t",$str_src);

    // Prepara o query (exemplo com 3 valors per linha)
     $query_insert = "INSERT INTO TAB_GARDE_ACT "
     ."( "
     ."campo1, "
     ."campo2, "
     ."campo3 "
     .") "
     ."VALUES "
     ."("
     ."'".$tab[0]."', "
     ."'".$tab[1]."', "
    ."'".$tab[2]."' "
    .") ";

     //Fazer o query (depende do que vc usa Mysql, mysqli, dbp, postgress...)
     $result = sql_query($connector,$query_insert);
 }

 // Fechar documento
 fclose($h_src);
```

Precisa (normal!) abrir a conexão com a BDD. Se vc tem um monte de dados, vc pode usar um chamada SQL so. Para isso, precisa usar mysql_insert_array().

Comment: Só uma observação: funções mysql_* estão obsoletas a desde o PHP 5.5. Prefira usar MySQLi ou PDO. Veja mais aqui: http://www.ultimatephp.com.br/php-por-que-nao-utilizar-funcoes-mysql   Quanto a inserir diversos valores de uma só vez, veja este post: http://rberaldo.com.br/inserindo-multiplos-registros-em-tabela-de-banco-de-dados

Comment: Valeu aiiiiiiiii